# How to fill the space between the header and the navigation on?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-helper

I am currently trying to fill the white space between the header and the navigation. I'm new to HTML and CSS, so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

I tried adding a CSS rule to reset the margin of the  element inside the `<header>`.

```css
header {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
header h4 {
  margin: 0;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #444;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
nav a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
.containers {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.tab-content {
  display: none;
}
.tab-content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="containers">
    <header>
      <h4>Infrastructural Company</h4>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <a href="#home" onclick="showTab('home')">Home</a>
      <a href="#services" onclick="showTab('services')">Services</a>
      <a href="#projects" onclick="showTab('projects')">Projects</a>
      <a href="#contact" onclick="showTab('contact')">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Do you want them all on the same line, as you have now?

Comment: `.containers{justify-content: flex-start;}` With this there will be no space between the header and the nav and all items will be at the left. If you want to center all the items then use `.containers{justify-content: center}`

Comment: Currently, it is `space-between` that's why the flex items (the header and the nav) are keeping the maximum space between them.

Answer (score 0):

Read more about [flex](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp);

```css
 .containers {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /* Stack items vertically */
    justify-content: flex-start; /* Align items to the top */
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #f0f0f0; /* Visualizing */
  }
```

I've added `flex-direction: column;` to stack the header and navigation vertically.

`justify-content: flex-start;` aligns the items to the top, ensuring there is no extra space between the header and navigation.

Feel free to adjust the background color and other styles to match your design preferences.